# CSS styled container with rounded corners and Gtk 3.6

Tags: css, gtk3

I'm develop application that uses Gtk CSS.

I need to get this result:

[image: ideal result]

Square with rounded corners is `EventBox` with name `content`.

---

Obvious CSS code works with Gtk 3.8 and Gtk 3.10:

```
#content
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

But with Gtk 3.6 or 3.4 it fails - background outside the border is not transparent:

[image: 3.6]

When I use this code:

```
#content
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, red);
}
```

I get this result (small dot at top-left):

[image]

---

What container or css I need to use to get the desired result?

Thanks for any help.

Python code for testing CSS:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

CSS_DATA = """
/* Some css */
"""

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(300, 300)
content = Gtk.EventBox()
content.props.name = "content"
content.props.margin = 50
button = Gtk.Button("button")
button.props.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
button.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER

content.add(button)
window.add(content)
window.show_all()

css = Gtk.CssProvider()
css.load_from_data(CSS_DATA)
style_context = window.get_style_context()
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), css, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

Gtk.main()
```